# I can only use asp.Net to put 3 side buttons on my project

Tags: asp.net, runatserver, aspbutton

Left Side is buttons.  The buttons won't do anything right now, my instructor wants us to just place them there and we will be writing the code in the next weeks lesson.

Inside the first table is my code for the buttons:

<asp:Button runat="server" Width="100%" Font-Bold="true" Text="Change Pictures" />

Inside second table which should be to right of buttons is the code for the website.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I found out from a codementor tutor, I would need to take both tables and put them inside a third table so they sit side by side.

So essentially both tables are really:

asp:TableCellTable1</asp:TableCell>
(asp:TableCell>Table2(/asp:TableCell>

Hope that helped the next person.